# AngularJS filter in controller 'startingAt'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have this array :

```
var items = [{
    'name': 'AA',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 1,
    'response' : false
},{
    'name': 'BAC',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 1,
    'response' : false
},{
    'name': 'CA,
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 2,
    'response' : true
},{
    'name': 'BAW,
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 2,
    'response' : true
}];
```

I have got one search bar and when the value changed it call to this function:

```
function comparator(valueSearchBar) {}
```

I want in that function to be able to filter the items array by name 'starting at'.

For example, if I search `A`, the function should return the first item (`AA`).
If I search `C`, it should return the `3º` position, `CA`. However, if I search `BA`, it should return one array with two items `BAC` and `BAW`.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the filter prototype.

```
function comparator(valueSearchBar) {
  var newItemsList = items.filter(
                       function(item) { 
                         return item.name.startsWith(name);
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [{
    'name': 'AA',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 1,
    'response' : false
},{
    'name': 'BAC',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 1,
    'response' : false
},{
    'name': 'CA',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 2,
    'response' : true
},{
    'name': 'BAW',
    'phone': '000 00 00 01',
    'time': '15:44',
    'priority': 2,
    'response' : true
}];
function comp(first) {
    var firstLetter = first.substring(0, 1);

    return items.filter(function( ii ) {
        return ii.name.substring(0, 1) == firstLetter;
    });
}
console.log( JSON.stringify(comp('B') ));
```

or

Answer (score 0):

You can create an orderer filter using the regex "^" symbol. I have created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/nr7bg6up/

The idea is to call the filter function using the pipe symbol in your ng-repeat:

```
   <input ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
   <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchInOrder">
       {{item.name}}
   </div>
```

And then use the regex in the "searchInOrder" filter function:

```
$scope.searchInOrder = function (selection)
    {
        if($scope.search)
        {
            var regEx = new RegExp("^"+$scope.search, "i"); 
            if(selection.name.match(regEx))
            {
                return selection;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return selection;
        }
    }
```